# Randomly displaying strings

Tags: android, arrays, string, random, switch-statement

I made a pool of about 20 strings that each display different sayings.  I want one of those sayings to display to a text view on random.

I cast an integer as a random 1-20,

```
int randomNumber5 = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 20);
```

and created strings named randomString1, randomString2, etc...til it hits 20.

The best way I could think to do this, was assign each string a number between 1 and 20 as a case.

So:

```
switch(randomNumber5){
  case 1:
    mTheMessage.setText(R.string.randomString1);  
}
  case 2:
    mTheMessage.setText(R.string.randomString2);
```

but I feel like there is a better way to do this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array or list.

```
mTheMessage.setText(RandomString[randomNumber]);
```

Each element of RandomString[] is loaded with a message.

Comment: How do I go about putting all the sayings into an array/list?

Comment: There are a number of ways: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp  (I'm assuming your code is javascript, though you didn't say.)

Answer (score 1):

I would say create an array of strings (the sayings) and get the random number to decide which index to access.

Comment: How do I go about putting all the sayings into an array/list?

Answer (score 1):

Your method would definitely work but if you had to change your requirements to display 100 or 1000 strings, typing 100 or 1000 cases would not too much fun.

I would stuff the strings in an array or list and return the string by the randomly generated index.